# vim doesn't show the command that is being typed

Tags: command-line

I was reading **vimtutor** and in lesson 2.1 there was this note about typing commands like **dw**:

```
NOTE: The letter  d  will appear on the last line of the screen as you type
    it.  Vim is waiting for you to type  w .  If you see another character
    than  d  you typed something wrong; press  <ESC>  and start over.
```

but I can't see the commands that I am typing in command line neither in vim or gvim. How can I fix that?

Comment: Related: [How to know commands I've been typing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656230/how-to-know-commands-ive-been-typing) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line into you .vimrc , either source it or restart vim.

```
set showcmd
```

And yes If you are experimenting with your vimrc and tired of sourcing it after every change, add this line.

```
autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc source %
```

Comment: @allsysed : Can you explain what the below command does

Comment: @aspiring1 `autocmd` means to automatically execute an action. `BufWritePost` is a condition for said autocmd, and means "after a buffer has been written". `.vimrc` is the file pattern to match. `source %` is the command, and it means to source the contents of the current file or buffer (don't remember exactly). The command can be interpreted as "When a file named `.vimrc` has been written, source it". Sourcing is equivalent to loading a file (I imagine there's a `:help source` for that)

Answer (score 17):

This behaviour is controlled by the `showcmd` option.

Try:

```
:set showcmd
```

and see if that brings it back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I had this in my _vimrc_. So I tried other things in vimrc and by disabling wildmenu it was fixed. Then I enabled wildmenu again and nothing changed. Now I don't know what was wrong!

Comment: When you edit your *vimrc* you can execute it in your running vim, using the command `:source /path/to/vimrc`. But this is not as clean as starting a fresh instance of Vim (because it won't reset any default settings you might have changed on the command line). So I find the cleanest way to test is to have two copies of Vim running, one where I edit my *vimrc* and another which I **restart** to test the results.

Answer (score 1):

You must have `set showcmd` **after** `set nocompatible` like this:

```
set nocompatible 
set showcmd
```

I don't know the reason but i faced the same problem and this worked with me.

Comment: This applies not just to `showcmd`, but to *many* settings, as documented in [`:help 'nocompatible'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27nocompatible%27) ;-) If you use a vimrc file, then `set nocompatible` is *already* used automatically! So there no need to add this option yourself ;-)